# Querying non XSD, RDF, etc., datatypes in RDF with SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql

This is the rdf code:

```xml
 <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://id.southampton.ac.uk/building/42">
    <ns0:notation xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" rdf:datatype="http://id.southampton.ac.uk/ns/building-code-scheme">42</ns0:notation>
  </rdf:Description>
```

I need to get the number `"42"`.  I tried this:

```
PREFIX soton: < http://id.southampton.ac.uk/ns/ >
PREFIX skos: < http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core# >

?location skos:notation  rdf:datatype=<http://id.southampton.ac.uk/ns/building-code-scheme>(?note)
```

or something like:

```
 ?location skos:notation soton:building-code-scheme(?note)
```

I know how to do it with the actual RDF datatypes like `xsd:integer`, but I don't know how to do it with the additional datatypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much easier to approach these problems if you can provide complete working data that we can use.  In this case, it's not too hard to make the RDF snippet into a complete RDF document.  For this answer, I will use the following data:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://id.southampton.ac.uk/building/42">
    <ns0:notation rdf:datatype="http://id.southampton.ac.uk/ns/building-code-scheme"
    >42</ns0:notation>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

If you're trying to get the literal value that is the notation of the `http://id.southampton.ac.uk/building/42`, then you can just ask for it directly with a SPARQL query like this one.

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
SELECT ?notation WHERE { 
  <http://id.southampton.ac.uk/building/42> skos:notation ?notation
}
```

Using Jena's ARQ command line tools, we get output like the following:

```
$ arq --data data.rdf --query query.sparql
---------------------------------------------------------------
| notation                                                    |
===============================================================
| "42"^^<http://id.southampton.ac.uk/ns/building-code-scheme> |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you want to get the lexical form of the literal, you can select that using [`str`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#func-str):

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
SELECT (STR(?notation) as ?strNotation) WHERE { 
  <http://id.southampton.ac.uk/building/42> skos:notation ?notation
}
```

which produces output that contains the string `"42"`:

```
$ arq --data data.rdf --query query.sparql
---------------
| strNotation |
===============
| "42"        |
---------------
```

If you had wanted to find the building that had the literal as its `skos:notation`, you'd need to write the literal into the SPARL query using the syntax described in [2.3.3 Matching Literals with Arbitrary Datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#matchArbDT) of the SPARQL recommendation.  That would look like this:

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
SELECT ?building WHERE { 
  ?building skos:notation "42"^^<http://id.southampton.ac.uk/ns/building-code-scheme>
}
```

You do not have to write the full IRI in the SPARQL query, however.  Just as you can use `xsd:integer` when the `xsd:` prefix is defined, you can use `ns:building-code-scheme` if you first define the `ns:` prefix as in the following.

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX ns: <http://id.southampton.ac.uk/ns/>
SELECT ?building WHERE { 
  ?building skos:notation "42"^^ns:building-code-scheme
}
```

Both queries produce the same output:

```
$ arq --data data.rdf --query query.sparql
---------------------------------------------
| building                                  |
=============================================
| <http://id.southampton.ac.uk/building/42> |
---------------------------------------------
```